# String replace in erlang

Tags: regex, string, erlang

When I'm doing this in erlang, I got following result.

```
19> re:replace("(9 and 10) or (11 and 12)","(9 and 10)","13",[{return,list}]).  
"(13) or (11 and 12)".
```

Is this correct?, why my answer isn't "`13 or (11 and 12)`" ?

Comment: The `(` and `)` create a group in a regex pattern. You need to either escape them or put inside `[...]`.

Comment: double escape, that is. You're working in the erl shell. So: 4> re:replace("(9 and 10) or (11 and 12)","\\\(9 and 10\\\)","13",[{return,list}]).